# count tabs in C (fails)

Tags: c, tabs, counting

So, I'm supposed to be creating a program in C to count: "blanks, tabs, and spaces".  My code is provided below (including comments). you'll see that I have commented the areas of the code that is tasked with counting, and displaying the count of, tabs.

As it stands, the program counts "Blanks" and "Lines" accurately, but "Tabs" always results in "0". I've combed over the tiny code again and again looking for typoes or something, but have found no reason why '\t' fails to be counted. Then I came here and read through a few posts dealing with this same challenge. Thus far, I have found nothing anywhere which would shed any light on the problem I am experiencing with my code.

please, look it over, compile it, and test it out yourself to verify.
If anyone can tell me where my mistake is, that is causing my code not to count "Tabs" (as desired), that would be fantastic.
thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* count blanks (" "), tabs (\t), and newlines (\n) */

main()
{
    int c, nb, nt, nl;

     nb = nt = nl = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c == ' ')
            ++nb;
        else if (c == '\t')
            ++nt;                       /* fails to accumulate count */
        else if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;

    printf("Spaces:\t%d\n", nb);
    printf("Tabs:\t%d\n", nt);       /* fails to report new tabs (\t) */
    printf("Lines:\t%d\n", nl);
}
```

Comment: replace `nb, nt, nl = 0;` with `nb = nt = nl = 0;`

Comment: i have no problem with the codes (except some warning due to nb, nt, nl = 0). tabs are counted correctly. i'm afraid that your os may have mapped tab to spaces. did you get expected count for spaces?

Comment: Tabs are tricky because visually it's impossible to tell the difference between tabs and a bunch of spaces. So if your tab count is zero, then the space count should be higher than expected.

Comment: For goodness sake put some braces around the contents of your `while()` loop. They may not be strictly necessary, but this is really bad style.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage No need to yell. I have been programming for 30 years, and I never used them. They make the code hard to read, and they often imply that the programmer does not know that they are not required.

Comment: @DYZ I'm not yelling. And since when did "not required" mean "should not be used"? White space is seldom *required* in C code, but it makes it a lot more readable. The same applies to braces, at least IMHO.

Comment: DaBler, I made the edit. no change in result.                     Spaces: 178
Tabs: 0
Lines: 20

Comment: @user3386109, I'm pretty sure that "tabs" are infact being counted as 4 spaces, however, when I use the program on this script which actually contains '\n' in the code on lines 18-20, I'm a bit surprised that it fails even to acknowledge that.

Comment: @shipping, how would I reedy that ( possibility of tabs mapped to spaces in my OS)?

Comment: No OS maps tabs to spaces!

Comment: @squeamishossifrage: White space is required between any two identifiers and integer constants. Considering declarations, they are actually very often required.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage, I'll consider resorting to stylistic matters after I've eliminated bugs and mastered enough of the C Programming Language to avoid problems like the one I'm currently experiencing.

Comment: I guess I could mention that my OS is Arch Linux.

Comment: Please update your question if you made changes to your code. There is no point in discussing the stale version.

Comment: @DYZ I made change: (replace nb, nt, nl = 0; with nb = nt = nl = 0;) but this had no effect at resolving the issue, so I reverted the code to it's original state ( in order to avoid unnecessarily compounding the problem). The original problem has not been solved.

Comment: But _please_ change the original code in the question.

Comment: @DYZ, this is the current code.

Comment: @DYZ, I just looked at the original post. I don't see where/how I wold go about "updating" it, other than to add a comment, as I am doing here.

Comment: How sure are you that there are truly tabs in the input file?  If you created the input file with an editor, the editor MAY convert tabs to spaces...  Have you performed a hexdump of the input file and confirmed tabs are contained therein???

Comment: @DYZ I am sorry as well, I assumed you knew the meaning of "it has since been changed back"...

Comment: @TonyB, I wrote the file with Visual Studio Code. I do not know how to perform a "hexdump" of the input file. No, I have not tried that.

Comment: But have you proved it...???  run "od -x filename", where filename is your input file.  Confirm it contains tabs (which are 0x09)

Comment: @TonyB, thanks, that solved it. I just tried it with a random file from /usr/bin and it worked like a charm.  So yeah, Visual Stidio Code seems like it possibly did convert TAB to SPACES.